# Can't boot from flash drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, mac, macosx

I am running macOS Sierra on a Macbook 2010. I followed the instructions at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0.

When I try to boot from the flash drive I get the following error message:

```
[   9.911831] Couldn't get size: 0x000000000000000e
[   9.911867] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[   9.929086] Couldn't get size: 0x000000000000000e
[   9.946311] Couldn't get size: 0x000000000000000e
[  10.447589] nouveau 0000:04:00.0:bus:MMIO write of 0000807e FAULT at 100c1c
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?